# Simulation of blocking assignments in always @ blocks

Tags: verilog, simulation

Tracking down some weird simulation results, I found that the use of blocking assignments at clock edges was the culprit. More specifically, different simulators seem to treat them differently.

Take the following example:

```
module test;

reg clk, foo, bar;

initial
begin
  clk = 0;
  foo = 0;
  bar = 0;
  #10 $finish;
end

always
  #1 clk = ~clk;

always @(posedge clk)
  foo = ~foo;

always @(posedge clk)
  bar <= foo;

endmodule
```

Running this in Xilinx' ISim gives the following waveform:

[image: Waveform produced by ISim]

This seems reasonable although I do find it a bit strange that a change in `foo` at a clock edge gets picked up by bar *at the same clock edge*.

The following waveform is produced by running the same example using Icarus Verilog:

[image: Waveform produced by Icarus Verilog]

This seems completely wrong to me. A change in `foo` from `0` to `1` is not picked up by `bar` at the same clock edge. However, a change in `foo` from `1` to `0` *does* get picked up by `bar` at the same clock edge (otherwise `bar` would change to `1` at the second positive clock edge I suppose).

So, I have two questions:

1. Which, if any, of these simulators is correct? In other words, how should the above code behave?
2. Are differences between simulators something we should always be aware of? If so, are there any guidelines on writing code that is deterministic across different simulators?

**Note:** I'm aware of the fact that using blocking assignments in `always @` blocks is not a good idea and that using a non-blocking assignment in my example gives logical and consistent results. I'm asking this question because I'm currently debugging some third-party simulation code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm no Verilog guru, but as I understand it (from here http://www.sigasi.com/content/verilogs-major-flaw amongst other places), using blocking assignments to communicate between clocked processes is asking for non-determinism.

Regarding part 2 - As I understand it... if you only use non-blocking assignments when you communicate between processes, you'll get deterministic behaviour across all simulators.  The non-determinism of blocking assignments is not a "simulator thing" - it's inherent in the way Verilog works.  Changing the order of the processes in the source files (for example) may change the order of the updates and hence the behaviour of the code, even within the same simulator.

Comment: After skimming through the Verilog standard, I guess you are correct. I would still like to have an answer on my second question, though. I'll wait a couple of days before accepting your answer to see if anything comes up.